# Library function to extract substring by position index

Tags: c, string, standard-library

In c,  is there a standard library function that will allow me to extract a substring from a given string,  by specifying the starting index,  and ending index of the string.  Also the substring is not null terminated within the superstring,  i. e,  getting a simple pointer to the beginning of the substring will not suffice to extract the substring.

Of course I can write a function to do what I want,  I merely want to know If any existing library function will suffice for my purpose.

Comment: No, there's no standard function for that.

Comment: If you are sure that there is no null in the source string you can use **char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)**
Copies up to n characters from the string pointed to by src to dest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in `C`, I maybe can assume that your string is a `char *`.

In this case, if you know the start and end index, you can just `memcpy` a part of your string to your substring.

This piece of code, for example, would print `"str"`:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  const char *c = "the string";
  char *start = &c[4];
  char *end = &c[7];
  // Note the + 1 here, to have a null terminated substring
  char *substr = (char *)calloc(1, end - start + 1);
  memcpy(substr, start, end - start);
  printf("%s\n", substr);
  return 0;
}
```

So, given a string `c` and two values, `4` and `7`, you can get the substring starting at index `4` and ending at index `7` - `1` (this is a normal semantic for "substringing", but you can easily change this code to include also the `end` character).